# Escaping backslash inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coldfusion

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    console.log(#Fileurl#);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://xyz:8800/aaa/bbb/ccc",
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{"file":"#Fileurl#"},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is the javascript code inside a coldfusion page. If I try to print "Fileurl" outside script,output is perfect.

output : D:\abc\FLV\238550_605_orion.mp4.

But inside javascript output is,

D:abcFLV238550_605_orion.mp4.

Actually we want to send url to delete the particular file.Reply is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you ever get this sorted out, are you sure you will be able to successfully delete a file on the user's machine?  I seem to recall having lack of permission issues with this sort of thing.

Comment: Previously we are able to do the same.But we changed the application from dynamic java project to grails. So we want to pass resource url to the specific  grails app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there is no way to do the task in javascript. So instead of

use ColdFusion's [jsstringformat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e31.html) to convert the **Fileurl** to

D:\abc\FLV\238550_605_orion.mp4

```
console.log("<cfoutput>JSStringFormat(Fileurl)</cfoutput>");
```

Comment: Perfect...outside javascript I just added <cfset jsString = JSStringFormat(#Fileurl#)> ..inside script used console.log("<cfoutput>#jsString#</cfoutput>") ....works fine..Thankyou.

Comment: Side note, no need for # signs here: JSStringFormat(#Fileurl#).

Comment: Thank you @Leigh.  In practice I have given, but it's not mandatory.. Thank you very much for improving it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ColdFusion 10+, you should use `encodeForJavaScript()` instead of `JSStringFormat()`. In addition, by putting the path to a network file in the client-side code, you're opening yourself up to a [Path Traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) attack.

The user could manipulate the JavaScript to point to different files and folders than what you're intending. If you're passing this to a delete function, you could be in for a world of trouble. Why not pass some file ID instead?

Comment: Yep.  Took the words the words right out of my mouth!

Answer (score 0):

Backslash has special meaning, you have to escape that. You can try to double the backslashes, or use proper url format like file://path/to/file with forward slashes.